# Can't see changes to the json file when the application is running

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET 6 Core application. There is a `serilog.json` file with the Serilog configuration. At runtime, if you change this file, Serilog does not see the change, but the reloadOnChange configuration parameter is true.

Method main of the `Program` class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

    if (isService)
    {
        var module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;

        if (module != null)
        {
            var pathToExe = module.FileName;
            var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
        }
    }

    SetLogger();

    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args);

    if (isService && RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        host.UseWindowsService();

    var builder = host.Build();

    try
    {
        builder.Run();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Service stopped
    }
}
```

Method SetLogger:

```
private static void SetLogger()
{
    var appsettingsConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    var serilogConfigurationFilePath = appsettingsConfiguration
        .GetSection("AppSettings:logger_config_file")
        .Get<string>();

    var serilogConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(serilogConfigurationFilePath, false, true)
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithThreadId()
        .Enrich.WithThreadName()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(serilogConfiguration)
        .CreateLogger();

    ChangeToken.OnChange(() => serilogConfiguration.GetReloadToken(), () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("text");
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you change the file?

Comment: Manually. After the restart of the application everything is working. So the problem is that the application does not see the changes at runtime.

Comment: You change appsettings.json file? for the serilog configuration file? what type of changes do you make? Can you add these details in the question itself?

Comment: I change the serilog.json file with the Serilog configuration. I change the minimum log level. And application does not see these changes. After restart everything is working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload Serilog JSON Configuration on changes in .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449596/reload-serilog-json-configuration-on-changes-in-net-core-2-1)

Comment: In another application with the same code, everything works. So it should work here too, I think. But doesn't work.

Comment: @VladPopovschi Maybe you're changing the main `appsettings.json` file and not the one in the build directory.